# HTML table change cell color

Tags: javascript, html-table, background-color, tablecell

I have an HTML table to which i add rows when button is clicked. That part work fine:

```
function ic_add_supplier_line(){
   var table = document.getElementById("ic_current_pricing");
   var count = $('#ic_current_pricing tr').length;
   var row = table.insertRow(count); 
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
     var cell = row.insertCell(i); 
     var cell_id = "ic_q_" + String(i) +"_" + String(count)
     cell.innerHTML = "<input id=" + cell_id + " style='width:100%;' type='text' ondblclick='select_supplier(this.id)' >" 
  } 
}
```

When cell is double clicked I want the cell background color to change.

```
  function select_supplier(elm_id) {
     var cur_row = elm_id.slice(-1)
     var table = document.getElementById("ic_current_pricing");
     var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr") ;
     for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
        if (i== cur_row){
           for (j =0; j<8; j++){
               rows[i].cells[j].className="on"
           }    
        }else{
           for (j =0; j<8; j++){
           rows[i].cells[j].className=""        
        }
     }
   }
}
```

and CSS

```
.on{
   background-color:green ;
 }
```

Only border/outline is changing color. Cell remains white.
Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a mix of Vanillia JS and jQuery here, you could easily use jQuery and reduce the execution time needed here. Can you add the full html code and samples? Is the "on" class name being applied to the tr row you clicked on?

Comment: @GrandIQ. I am fairly new to all of this, hence the mixture of codes. However, the function that supposed to change color of the cell is Vanilla JS i believe. At this point, i'm not really worried about execution speed, just want to get functionality going. I tried to apply "on" class to both row and cells. Results are the same. Color is changing for outline of the cell only.

Comment: So you manually added the "on" class to random row cells but the border color is changing? Please check your inspect tool and see if there is a conflict of class names that are restricting your custom class of "on". If you see multiple elements changing your "tr" row cells color then you might be having a conflict of styling.

Comment: @GrandIQ. Will do. But i am certain there is no class name conflicts.

Comment: Would you mind joining a chat room so we could try to resolve this?

Comment: Join me here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196086/room-for-grandiq-and-goryef

Comment: see my shorter solution with event delegation ?

Comment: @MisterJojo. Thanks for your input. I made modification based on GranIQ suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the input field generated overlapped the actual cell, so when the color change was occurring it wouldn't display the entire cell since the input field was taking 99% of it. By altering and assigning the "on" class to effect the input fields, we got the final result that OP desired.

Comment: GrandIQ Went above and beyond helping me to solve this.

Comment: That's what we do here! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

a solution, expect  corresponding ?
(more simple to change entire row color _ and ES6 syntax...)

```js
const ic_Table = document.querySelector("#ic_current_pricing tbody")

function ic_add_supplier_line()
  {
  let count = ic_Table.rows.length
   , newRow = ic_Table.insertRow( count )
  for (let i=0; i < 4; i++)   // changed 8 to 4 
    {
    newRow
      .insertCell(i)
      .innerHTML = `<input id="ic_${i}_${count}" type="text" >` 
    } 
  }

ic_Table.ondblclick=e=>  // event delegation for double click for every <input
  {
  if(!e.target.tagName.toLowerCase=='input') return
  let TR_parent = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
  ic_Table.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(xTR=> xTR.className = (xTR===TR_parent) ? 'on' : '' )
  }

R_plus.onclick = ic_add_supplier_line
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 1em }
td { border: 1px solid grey; padding: .5em 0; height: 1em; width:110px; text-align:center; }

td input[type=text] { width:80px !important  }

.on { background-color:green ; }
```

```html
<button id="R_plus">Add Row</button>

<table id="ic_current_pricing">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```